# How to change an entry's slug on EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT?

Tags: events, slug, modules, onsaveentry

My entries' titles are auto-generated from several fields values on first save.

When one of these fields values change, I would like to update the auto-generated slug also:

```php
Event::on(
    \craft\services\Elements::class,
    \craft\services\Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT,
    function (Event $event) {
        $entry = Entry::find()
            ->id($event->element->id)
            ->one();

        if ([] !== $entry) {
            $title = craft\helpers\StringHelper::toAscii($entry->id.'-'.$entry->title);
            $title = craft\helpers\StringHelper::toLowerCase($title);
            $title = str_replace(' ', '-', $title);

            //  I tried this below, but none works
            $entry->slug = $title; // ⬅️ Not working
            $entry->setFieldValue('slug', $title); // ⬅️ Error
            Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry); // ⬅️ Infinite loop
            $event->element->slug = $event->element->id; // ⬅️ Not working
        }
    }
);
```

Unfortunately, none of these methods works. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally use this simple solution, which works pretty fine:

```
Event::on(
    Element::class,
    Element::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE,
    function(craft\events\ModelEvent $event) {
        $entry = $event->sender;
        if (!\craft\helpers\ElementHelper::isDraftOrRevision($entry)) {
            if (!empty($entry->id)) {
                $entry->slug = $entry->title;
            }
        }
    },
    false
);
```

Where `$entry->slug = $entry->title` syncs the slug to the title if the entry is not new (`!empty($entry->id)`).

**UPDATE:**

```
$entry->slug = ($entry->title !== null) ? \craft\helpers\StringHelper::slugify($entry->title) : $entry->slug;
```

This prevents to get a wrong slug on first save.

Comment: Due to the draft changes, this is the right approach for Craft 3.2 and later.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the value in the DB directly instead of using the `Elements` service

```PHP
$entry = $event->element;
$elementId = $entry->id;
$siteId = $entry->siteId;
Craft::$app->getDb()->createCommand()
    ->update(
        '{{%elements_sites}}',
        ['slug' => ElementHelper::createSlug('new-slug')],
        [
            'elementId' => $elementId,
            'siteId'    => $siteId
        ]
    )->execute();
```

By the way the following condition `[] !== $entry` won't be any good when you fetch an element with `one()` because `one` returns an object of instance `ElementInterface` or `null` but never an empty array. You can check `!== null` instead and if you fetch things via `all` you can perform an empty check `if( empty($entries) === false)`

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I had never thought of the DB way. Thank you also for the other explanations and advice, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Another shorter and probably slightly more performant solution, using EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE:

```
/*
* Automatically update Element slugs to match the title if updated.
*/
Event::on(
    Element::class,
    Element::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE,
    function(craft\events\ModelEvent $event) {
        $entry = $event->sender;
        $entry->slug = ElementHelper::createSlug($entry->title);
    },
    false
);
```

Comment: This solution is not working, you should review the suggested code.

Comment: Works fine for me (it's tested and being used). Did you actually try it?

Comment: @RomainPoirier it will not work with EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT but it does with EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT

Comment: Yep, I tried but but too quickly, I'm sorry. I was missing the loading of `craft\base\Element` and `craft\helpers\ElementHelper`.
Would you use `EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT` instead of `EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE`? I can't find official reference of `EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE` in the Craft 3 docs.
If you know, can you explain the utility of `false` at the end? Thank you!

Comment: Since recent Craft updates, `$entry->slug = ElementHelper::createSlug($entry->title);` doesn't works as expected: the slug is sometimes saved as empty. Delete `$entry->slug =` and only keep `ElementHelper::createSlug($entry->title);` seems to fix it.